# Django - filtering on foreign key on third table

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to filter a table in Django based on the value of a particular field of a ForeignKey which is a filed of a third table ForignKey.

```
class A(models.Model):
    user_type = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=32)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=512)

class B(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    user_type = models.ForeignKey(A,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class C(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(B,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    test = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=512)
```

here is the query that I wish to make :
I want to query on the `C` and find the `user_type_id` on the `B` then filter `user_type` value on `A`
something like this (just for showing what I want):

```
models.C.objects.filter(test="test").filter(B__user_type_id__A__user_type = 1)
```

final result:
 I want to get all of the data that `test="test"` in table `C` and `user_type = 1` in table A

Comment: How are `C` and `B` related here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem okey I think I forgot to add that , let me edit it

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited that. I'm using a ForeignKey to relate C to B and B to A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `user_type` field on the `A` model is a `CharField`. So you can not filter on a number. You can however filter on a value of that `user_type` field:

```
C.objects.filter(test='test', b__user_type__user_type='my_user_type_value')
```

Or you can filter on the primary key of the `A` object:

```
C.objects.filter(test='test', b__user_type_id=1)
```